# Sharepoint workflow assignment email doesn't preserve lookups

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I am using Sharepoint workflow 2013 and my issue is with assignment email body in the action "Start a task process".
Whenever I add lookups using "Add or Change Lookup" button, it is changed to this "{#index of the lookup}", and if i added just one lookup i get the following error.

> Using the special characters '[%%]' or '[%xxx%] in any string, or using the special character '{' in a string that also contains a workflow lookup, may corrupt the string and cause an unexpected result when the workflow runs.

I follow these steps:

1. From the drop down on the right of the "start a task process" action, I choose properties.
2. I open "AssignmentEmailBody" string builder.
   [Assignment Email Option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gahhK.png)
3. I add my lookups to be used the email.
   [LookUp Added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3GhQ.png)
4. I press ok for the string builder window and ok for the properties window.
5. If I opened the properties again I find the lookups replaced.
   [Replaced lookup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XILKw.png)

I want to preserve the lookups.

Any help would appreciated.